# NullReferenceException during .exe run, but not during debug

Tags: c#, static, nullreferenceexception

During the construction of my Window LoginSystem, a NullReferenceException is being thrown only when running the application through the .exe.

While debugging, everything works perfectly fine however.

Code which calls the LoginSystem window:

```
LoginSystem ls = new LoginSystem();
ls.Show();
```

Where I've found the problem to be in my LoginSystem class:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Login.con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["thuisDB"].ConnectionString);
    ...
}
```

Just in case you're wondering:

```
public class Login
{
    public static SqlConnection con = null;
    ...
}
```

Link to stack trace:
[HERE](http://pastebin.com/PapDccSD)

PS: This line (`Login.con = new SqlConnection(....)` is the first time `Login.con` gets called, as the only code using that static var are in a class which LoginSystem is supposed to make.

EDIT: This question is NOT about me asking what a NullRef is or how to fix it, it was merely a single event where I didn't know why it was being thrown & didn't know how to debug it.

Comment: Add more code, specially where the `NullPointerException` happens.

Comment: That's the only code that should be relevant though, don't think any of my other code would be relevant at all to this NullReference

Comment: It sounds like `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` is null, or the result coming out of the collection. Try doing `var string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["thuisDB"];` and see if the value is null, before accessing `ConnectionString`

Comment: That thought has crossed my mind as well, however I'm not entirely sure as to how I should test for that :|

Comment: Just access each component one at a time. `var conStrings = Configurationmanager.ConnectionStrings;` then `var result = conStrings["thuisDB"];` then lastly `string str = result.ConnectionString;`. After each step, do a null check before moving forward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Alex Hardly, I'm not asking what a NullRef is, I was asking why it was being thrown, as I thought the app.config was embedded in the .exe, now that I know it's not, it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectionStrings["thuisDB"]` will be null if you are running the `.exe` in a folder where it can't find the configuration file.

Look for something like `MyProgram.exe.config` and make sure that is in the same folder as your executable file.

Comment: It's not just a matter checking the config is in the same folder as the exe, you also have to make sure you've got permission to access it - you can't just indiscriminately hit your app location under %PROGRAMFILES% anymore.

Comment: @Kazetsukai I see, I thought the app.config was automatically added to the exe as some sort of resource.